# Why is NuGet forcing an upgrade of a dependency that's already met?

Tags: spring, nunit, nuget

I'm trying to install Spring.Testing.NUnit with NuGet, and it's forcing me to update a dependency, even though I already have an acceptable version. It's not even updating it to the latest version, which is 2.6.0.

I can install with `-IgnoreDependencies`, but when I do, I error out running tests with the error `Could not load file or assembly 'nunit.framework, Version=2.6.0.12051`
Is the Spring.Testing.NUnit package wrong about what version of NUnit it requires?

```
PM> Install-Package NUnit -Version 2.5.7.10213
'NUnit 2.5.7.10213' already installed.
Successfully added 'NUnit 2.5.7.10213' to Services.Tests.Unit.

PM> Install-Package Spring.Testing.NUnit
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Common.Logging (= 1.2.0)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'NUnit (= 2.5.7)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Spring.Core (= 1.3.2)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Spring.Data (= 1.3.2)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Spring.Aop (= 1.3.2)'.
Successfully installed 'NUnit 2.5.10.11092'.
Successfully installed 'Spring.Testing.NUnit 1.3.2'.
Successfully removed 'NUnit 2.5.7.10213' from Services.Tests.Unit.
Successfully added 'NUnit 2.5.10.11092' to Services.Tests.Unit.
Successfully added 'Spring.Testing.NUnit 1.3.2' to Services.Tests.Unit.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring.Testing.Packages requires NUnit >= 2.5.7. NuGet considers the third part of the version string to be safe to update to (in general, it's not specific to this package). In this case, NuGet will pick the highest possible case where the version is at least 2.5.7 and lower than 2.6.

Comment: You can also use the `-IgnoreDependencies` switch when doing `Install-Package` which will [tell NuGet not to retrieve any dependencies.](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/package-manager-console-powershell-reference#Install-Package)